# RecyclerView Endless scroll not working with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

My **AsyncTask** loads data from json url and stores in object. It loads all data in object once.

```
itemname.add(new ITNAME(CID, itemName));
```

And it loads data on recycler view at once. I want adapter to not show all data at once, i want it to show first 10 items and when scroll to end load another 10. I added onScrolled method in recycler adapter :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        Log.e("Total Item Count:", String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
        visibleThreshold = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        Log.e("Visi Item Count:", String.valueOf(visibleThreshold));
        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached
            // Do something
            if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
            }
            loading = true;
        }
    }
});
```

But it loads all data. I think its because async task loads data at once and pass it to adapter:

```
mAdapter = new ITEMListAdapter(ITEMListActivity.this, itemname, recyclerview);
```

I dont want to change my async task because its working fine and i want data to be fetched at once. I tried to do like this https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e but not working. I searched a lot but lots of example are like this http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html , they use loop to load limited data at start and then loop again at load. These example are very different from my code because my data is pre loaded in object. All i want is that to load limited data at start and then load next set of data on scroll and so on....

Answer (score 0):

If you load all your data, but only want to display a part of it (you mentioned 10 items) than simply split your amount of items in to lists.

The first contains all data and the second is empty. When receiving data from the asynctask cut the amount of items out of the first list and put them in your second one.

The second list is for your adapter. After the removing and adding of items you inform the ui, that your list has new items (e.g. notifyDataSetChanged). When scrolling has reached the bottom you repeat this till your first list is empty.

Hope this will give an idea.